# How to add a hyperlink in jenkins build description using scripted pipeline

Tags: java, html, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Using jenkins build description plug in I want to print a path of my network drive.

Below code is working fine.

```
        stage('print') {
            env.SMBuildDescription="Build path:"+"${buildpath}"
            currentBuild.description=SMBuildDescription
        }
```

But I want to add build path as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
stage('print') {
            currentBuild.description = """Build path: <a href="${buildpath}">Link</a> """
        }
```

This will only work if `Markup Formatter` is set to `Safe HTML` (rather than `Plain text`) under /configureSecurity/ on your Jenkins instance.

Comment: This just prints the hyperlink text when we tried it..

Comment: I've just edited the answer: Markup Formatter setting needs to be Safe HTML for this to work (under Configure Global Security).

Comment: I had the same issue, was trying without safe HTML. Finally, it worked, thanks :)